# Sleeping Beauty and Snow White in the same movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

This may be a bit different than many identify-this-movie questions, but my five year old daughter's descriptions are about as vague as memories of movies I watched in my childhood, so I think it fits.

She is insisting she watched a film with both Snow White and the Seven Dwarves, and Sleeping Beauty in it. She likes to watch it again, but I can't identify the movie. It should be an animated movie.

When I ask if she can be confusing the part where Snow White "falls asleep" with the story of Sleeping Beauty, she says she knows both stories well and she is not mixing up anything with anything. This had both characters in it. She says Snow White falls asleep when her finger is pricked with a needle (not the poisonous apple).

She says the villain in the film (a female character) was named "delavorte". This sounds like it could be a good clue, but how to correctly spell it, is unfortunately out of question altogether.

She apparently watched this film last year in kindergarten/preschool, but she going to another school now, so I can't trace the source. It has also been some time. Google happily provides me pages with Sleeping Beauty and Snow White in them, which are plentiful.

Of course, since my daughter is five, she may have imagined this, dreamt it, heard it from somewhere, or really might be mixing up who knows what with what. So I'm asking my question well aware that there may be no answer. I'd also like to apologize in advance for any misleading clues she might have provided. That said we are still hopeful, and will appreciate any help, so she could have a chance to rewatch the film, or be rightfully persuaded it does not exist.

Comment: I got a "match" on "The 10th Kingdom" but there's no way a five year old would be watching that. Too long.

Comment: I believe all of these characters also exist in the Shrek universe

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your daughter can rest easy; she's absolutely right. You are looking for [The Seventh Dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seventh_Dwarf) (2014), a German 3D-animated film based on *Sleeping Beauty* that borrows characters from *Snow White* (and other fairy tales).

> In the castle Fantabularasa there is a big celebration because of the 18th birthday of Princess Rose, who has been cursed by **the evil ice fairy, *Dellamorta***. If she gets **pricked with a sharp object before midnight**, the whole kingdom will sleep for one hundred years. Thus, the princess is required to wear armor. Everything goes according to plan until clumsy Bobo, the seventh dwarf, makes a big mistake and Dellamorta's curse is fulfilled. Only with a kiss of true love the curse can be stopped, but Dellamorta captures the Kitchen Boy, Jack, who loves Rose. With the help of a dragon named Burner, **the dwarves search for the "Prince Charming"**.

Here's the trailer:

Comment: Be aware that if you're in the US, there might be a few things in this movie that are a little unexpected for a children's movie (since it is foreign).  We watched this on Netflix (I think, or Amazon), and there is a dragon that no one likes.  He is sad, so he ties a rope around is neck and ties that to a boulder, and then throws the bolder off of a mountain to try and kill himself.  Stuff like that and the fact that it overall just wasn't a very good movie means we're not going to watch it again.

Comment: It appears that Snow White is not in this movie (unless very briefly, as she exists in the background universe), but with the dwarfs and the name of the villain, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: "Dellamorta" with swapped word parts is the name of a [famous Italian sausage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortadella). See also Fan[tabularasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa).